# How to set "distribution environment" in QuickBlox 2.7.1 for IOS to use push notifications with distribution certificate

Tags: quickblox

I use a distribution certificate to send Push notifications from QuickBlox. But I can't send any message from the Admin Panel. Always, I have this error:

> "APNS (Apple Push) is not enabled for the current application. Please
>   enable this notification channel in the settings tab of the admin
>   panel"

I have tried to understand what exactly it means, and found out that my subscribed with QuickBlox device has "Environment" field equal to "Development". So, I assumed that it could be a problem. My application sends to the "quickblox" parameter "environment=development". I tried to change this parameter inside my application, using advises from articles from "StackOverFlow". They explained that I can use QBSettings class methods to set environment to "Production", but I can't find for QuickBlox 2.7.1 any methods which can change this parameter to "production".

Answer (score 0):

For SDK v2.7.1 you don't need to set the environment.

You get this error because there are no certificates for Push Notifications.

To be able to send notifications to APNS, you need to upload 2 APNS certificates to your Admin Panel. See [our tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates) for creating your APNS certificates.
Please make sure you keep the certificates up to date. We won't be able to send the APNS messages for you once certificates expire.